# Не запускается Debug при использовании QCameraViewfinder

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Господа! Хочу обратить ваше внимание на следующюю проблему. 
Есть небольшой код:

**.cpp**

```
#include "ZCamera.h"
#include <QCameraViewfinder>
#include <QCameraInfo>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

ZCamera::ZCamera(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    auto camera = new QCamera(this);
    auto finder = new QCameraViewfinder();
    camera->setViewfinder(finder);

    auto lay = new QHBoxLayout();
    lay->addWidget(finder);
    setLayout(lay);
}
```

**.pro**

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += multimedia multimediawidgets
```

Поведение:

**Win 7:** Работает debug и release

**Win 8.1:** Ничего не работает

**Win 10:** Работает только release

Во всех случаях .dll находятся в папке с .exe.
Данные проблемы появляются когда в проект добавляется и создается `QCameraViewfinder`. Он же за собой тянет Qt5Opengld.dll(Debug), которая ругается на Qt5Guid.dll, а имеено на отсутсвие функции 
`?glGetTexLevelParameteriv@QOpenGLFunctions_1_1@@QAEXIHIPAH@Z`

Визуально все это выглядит так:

**Ошибка запуска .exe:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Dependency Walker:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же, для тестирования, были прописаны пути \bin и \lib в `PATH`, но ничего не поменялось.

Qt 5.9.1.
MSVS 2015.
На всех машинах стоит одна и таже сборка Qt.
В случаях без `QCameraViewfinder` все работает как положено на всех машинах.

Comment: я бы сказал, что у вас собран QT без opengl

Comment: или один и тот же .ехе работает на 7-ке, но не работает в 8-ке и 10-ке?

Comment: "я бы сказал, что у вас собран QT без opengl" - собран с opengl (работает на 7-ке как доказательство). Екзешник собирается везде свой.

Comment: @Madisson , а если взять бинарник, собранный на 7-ке, и запустить на 8 или 10, запускается?

Comment: " а если взять бинарник, собранный на 7-ке, и запустить на 8 или 10, запускается?" - тоже самое

Comment: линкуетесь статически или динамически? если динамически, то рядом с .ехе-шником лежат дебажные версии либ?

Comment: для динамической линковки советую деплой-тул: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html (QTDIR/bin/windeployqt)

Comment: "линкуетесь статически или динамически?" - Динамически. Все либы лежат рядом.

Comment: я бы попробовал загрузить Qt5OpenGL.dll вручную с помощью QLibrary и поискать эту функцию на разных системах, может какие мысли появятся ...